# How to log every http.request made in Node

Tags: node.js

I want log every http request being made by a particular node app, and all of its modules. Wrapping requests in a function could work for all non-module code, the disadvantage would obviously be it doesn't include module code, and be cumbersome to do.

This is for apps already in production, only other option I thought of was tcpdump.

Comment: Maybe https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest and especially  https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_connect helps. You can basically build your own proxy as far as i understand this

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Setting `NODE_DEBUG=http` will make node log out detailed HTTP request information to the console.

Examples:

```
NODE_DEBUG=http,http2 node index.js

NODE_DEBUG=http,http2 npm start
```

---

For more information see:

- [`NODE_DEBUG documentation`](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#node_debugmodule)
- This blog post: [Debugging tools and practices in node.js](https://web.archive.org/web/20210512012549/https://www.alxolr.com/articles/debugging-tools-and-practices-in-node-js#debug-nodejs-internals-with-node_debug).

As of 2023-12-06, this is the list of the available `NODE_DEBUG` attributes (based on the blog post above and checking the nodejs source code):

> - child_process
> - cluster
> - esm
> - fs
> - http
> - https
> - http2
> - inspect
> - module
> - net
> - policy
> - repl
> - source_map
> - stream
> - stream_socket
> - test
> - test_runner
> - timer
> - tls
> - tracing
> - worker

You can pass multiple modules as a comma-separated list: `NODE_DEBUG=http,http2,tls`

---

**How to find the module IDs in nodejs source code:**

Unfortunately, there isn't a listing of the available debug module IDs in the nodejs documentation.

To find the IDs in the source: search/grep the nodejs `.js` files for `.debuglog(` usage:

```
# Grep inside the nodejs project
$ grep -r -E --color "\.debuglog\('" nodejs/lib
```

This will return results like:

```
let debug = require('internal/util/debuglog').debuglog('esm', (fn) => {

let debug = require('internal/util/debuglog').debuglog('http2', (fn) => {
```

The string passed to `.debuglog(...)` (e.g. 'esm' and 'http2') is the module id that can be passed to `NODE_DEBUG`.

Comment: No way to log http body?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest / least intrusive way is with a web proxy. Either an off the shelf one or one you write yourself in node.  The machines the apps live on would have to get configured* to send all outbound traffic through the proxy and then the proxy can log the traffic.  Details on implementation will vary based on which proxy/ approach you pick.

*Arguably, there are ways to do this such that the machines don't even know they're being proxied, but I've found in practice that's really hard to get right, especially with https traffic

Comment: Hi! I'm interested in this solution, do you have any reference like articles or tuts to implement this?

Comment: @kafinsalim proxyman

Answer (score 0):

In 2022, you can use grackle_tracking library. It helps you track all traffic, errors and analytics into your database or just to the console https://www.getgrackle.com/analytics_and_tracking

Answer (score -4):

Check HTTP request logger called Morgan [here](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan)

Comment: That's incoming requests I'm talking about node making http.request calls